# Automatically remove the selected option in drop down when the row is cloned

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function cloneRow() {
  var row = document.getElementById("dropdowns");
  var table = document.getElementById("tableDrop");
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "dropdowns";
  table.appendChild(clone);
  var x = document.getElementById("beansDrop");
  x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <form method="post" action="adeliveries.php">
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>Supplier:</td>
        <td id="num">
          <select name="num">
            <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)):;?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row1[3];?>">
              <?php echo $row1[1], " - " , $row1[3];?>
            </option>
            <?php endwhile;?>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <table id="tableDrop">
        <tr>
          <th>
            <h5>COFFEE BEAN</h5>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h5>QUANTITY(kg)</h5>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h5>REMOVE ORDER</h5>
          </th>
        </tr>

        <tr id="dropdowns">
          <td id="beansDropdown">
            <select name="beans[]" id="beansDrop">
              <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row1[1], " - ";?>">
                <?php echo $row1[1];?>
              </option>
              <?php endwhile;?>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td id="quantity">
            <input type="number" name="quan[]" placeholder="enter quantity" required>
          </td>
          <td id="remove">
            <input type="button" value="&#10006;" onclick="RemoveOrder()">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <table>
      <br>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="cloneRow()" value="Add Order" class="btn btn-secondary" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="abc" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm creating a simple order form where the user would select a coffee bean category from a drop down menu and input the quantity. There is an add order button where it would clone the row if ever the user would wish to order another. Is there anything I could do to hide or remove the selected bean/s automatically when I click Add Order? Because it just simply clones the row.

I have tried looping but I get confused on the logic of it.

Every time I clone the row it would be also deleted on every drop down including the drop down where I selected it from.

```js
function cloneRow(){
  var row = document.getElementById("dropdowns");
  var table = document.getElementById("tableDrop");
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "dropdowns";
  table.appendChild(clone);
  var x = document.getElementById("beansDrop");
  x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
}
```

```html
<tr id="dropdowns">                                          
  <td id="beansDropdown">
    <select name="beans[]" id="beansDrop">
      <option value="beans1">beans1</option>
      <option value="beans2">beans2</option>
      <option value="beans3">beans3</option>
      <option value="beans4">beans4</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td id="quantity">
    <input type="number" name="quan[]" placeholder="enter quantity" required>
  </td>
  <td id="remove">
    <input type="button" value="&#10006;" onclick="RemoveOrder()">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The php code in your markup was breaking the example code snippet, so I converted it to static example markup.

Comment: I also added the missing button to trigger the cloning as well as the `<table>` so we have a working minimal example.

Comment: Although it's not the problem that you are having, but when you clone you are duplicating IDs and they are meant to be unique.

Comment: @imvain2 I've figured out that logic lately but when I try to do it, I am confused on how to code it already. I am not used to JavaScript that much and I have struggles in structuring the codes. Though I get some of the logic, I struggle to apply it in my code.

Comment: @Connum I already edited the snippet and added some parts of the html file.

Comment: So... You basically broke the working example I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all id selector should be unique so it's better to use class in that case. In your code, you always get the first dropdown and removing the selected value. To make it works get the last dropdown, clone it and remove the selected value from the clone.

```js
function cloneRow(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var row = document.querySelector(".dropdowns:last-child");
  var tableBody = document.querySelector("#tableDrop tbody");
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
  clone.querySelector('.beansDrop').remove(row.querySelector('.beansDrop').selectedIndex);
  tableBody.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<table id="tableDrop">
  <tr class="dropdowns">
    <td class="beansDropdown">
      <select name="beans[]" class="beansDrop">
        <option value="beans1">beans1</option>
        <option value="beans2">beans2</option>
        <option value="beans3">beans3</option>
        <option value="beans4">beans4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="quantity">
      <input type="number" name="quan[]" placeholder="enter quantity" required>
    </td>
    <td id="remove">
      <input type="button" value="&#10006;" onclick="RemoveOrder()">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onClick="cloneRow(event)" type="button">add order</button>
```

**FYI :** If you want to remove the selected element from all other dropdowns then you have to iterate over all dropdowns.

---

With disabling instead of  removing element.

```js
function cloneRow(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var row = document.querySelector(".dropdowns:last-child");
  var tableBody = document.querySelector("#tableDrop tbody");
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
  var clonedDrop = clone.querySelector('.beansDrop');
  var lastDrop = row.querySelector('.beansDrop');
  clonedDrop.value = '';
  if (lastDrop.selectedIndex != -1) clonedDrop.options[lastDrop.selectedIndex].disabled = true;
  tableBody.appendChild(clone);
}


function RemoveOrder(ele) {
  var row = ele.closest('tr');
  var drop = row.querySelector('.beansDrop');
  var alldrop = document.querySelectorAll('.beansDrop');
  if (drop.selectedIndex != -1)
    alldrop.forEach(ele => ele.options[drop.selectedIndex].disabled = false)
  row.remove();
}
```

```html
<table id="tableDrop">
  <tr class="dropdowns">
    <td class="beansDropdown">
      <select name="beans[]" class="beansDrop">
        <option value="beans1">beans1</option>
        <option value="beans2">beans2</option>
        <option value="beans3">beans3</option>
        <option value="beans4">beans4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="quantity">
      <input type="number" name="quan[]" placeholder="enter quantity" required>
    </td>
    <td id="remove">
      <input type="button" value="&#10006;" onclick="RemoveOrder(this)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onClick="cloneRow(event)" type="button">add order</button>
```

**FYI :** To update disabled property when changing the dropdown you have to implement change event handler.

Comment: I tried to integrate this code on my code, also double checked, and if I click the "Add Order" button, it would just refresh me to the same page and does not clone the row.

Comment: @JaverickCynjynnP.Aqui :  `<button onClick="cloneRow()" type="button">add order</button>` .. add `type` attribute

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help, it worked! But there is a minimal problem, when I remove an order and I would click "add order", the latest drop down would not already show the removed bean and cannot be selected anymore. Is there a way to show the bean again on other drop downs when it is removed?

Comment: @JaverickCynjynnP.Aqui : it's better to disable instead of removing then

Comment: Oh that's a great idea! It could also be a solution. Could you help me on modifying the code again?

Comment: @JaverickCynjynnP.Aqui : let me try

Comment: @JaverickCynjynnP.Aqui :  added

Comment: I tried to integrate the code again but when I remove an order, for example, I would select bean1 from row 1 then click add row, bean1 is disabled and i would select bean2 from row 2, but when I click the remove order on row 1, bean1 is still disabled.

Comment: @JaverickCynjynnP.Aqui as i'd added in the last note you have to bind a change event handler and then need to do the changes

Comment: How do you bind a change event handler into it? Sorry, I'm still not used to JavaScript and I've been trying to do this for three days already and still trying to figure out this problem.

Comment: and should i change `<button onClick="cloneRow(event)" type="button">add order</button>` to `<button onClick="cloneRow(e)" type="button">add order</button>` ?

Comment: @JaverickCynjynnP : use onchange

Comment: <select name="beans[]" class="beansDrop" onchange="change(this)"> like this?

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you a lot for helping me. Have a great day ahead, Pranav.